# how to assign colnames for multiple dataframes from their first row in R environment

Tags: r, get, names

I am listing all the data frames in a vector and doing different operations on data frames by calling them from the vector (list_all). I am trying to assign colnames to each dataframe using its first row.

```
#table_1
           V1                V2              V3                V4              V5
1:      caffeine              ACHE            Adora1            ADORA1           Adora2a
2:                   7.25-    7.25    15.00-   44.00    44.00-   49.00     9.40-   48.10

#table_2
             V1     V2
1: paraxanthine daf-12
2:                  NA

#table_3

             V1              V2              V3              V4              
1: theophylline          Adora1          ADORA1         Adora2a         
2:                 0.70-  26.00    0.00-  20.00    1.31-  25.30   

list_all <- c("table_1","table_2","table_3") # this list was derived from previous code of 60 lines
n_drugs <- 3
drug_names <- c("caffeine","paraxanthine","theophylline")
output_final <- matrix(ncol=n_drugs , nrow=1)

for (t in 1:length(list_all)){
    output_final[t] <- paste(drug_names[t],"output_final", sep = "_")
    names_all <- c()
    names_all[t,] <- unlist(c(as.character(get(noquote(list_all[t]))[1,])))    #saving colnames in 'names_all'
    names_all[t,1] <- c("drug_name")      # change first column name
    assign(output_final[t],setnames(get(noquote(list_all[t])),colnames(get(noquote(list_all[t]))),names_all[t,]))
  }
```

When I run this code line by line it works but when I make funtion and run that funtion I am getting error

"Error in get(noquote(list_all[t])) : object 'NA' not found". Help me out

Comment: colnames showing up in the first row of your dataframe is usually a sign that you should have done something like `read.csv(..., header=TRUE)` when you first read your data, and it's much easier to fix at that stage than trying to do whatever it is you're attempting here.

Comment: Please provide the code that doesn't work

Comment: It seems like you are trying something that makes sense in another programming language, but not necessarily R...... some more details about what you are trying to do would help

Comment: @ HubertL this is the code that doesn't work on given tables

Comment: @mr_swap: from your example data it really looks like the problem lies with how you read the data. Have you explored the options from whatever `read.<filetype>()` function you used to check if it can deal with the header more sensibly?

Comment: @ Rilcon42 , my script format big tables and make them short. Where I am stuck at is to changing names of all the tables in my environment. Do you know how one can store first row of each table and then use it to assign them column names

Comment: @ Marius I initially use .csv to load big table but then all operations were done on data tables. No I have not used read.<filetype>()....there is no file, all are data frames

Comment: Please also provide your data using `dput`

Comment: @ HubertL I don't know how to use dput, ....what my problem is, I am using 'noquote' to extract name of table from list_all. I use 'get' to fetch table. But unfortunately it doesn't work inside function, it works when I run code line by line

Answer (score 2):

Like the above comments suggest, it should be easier to deal with this when importing data, e.g. `read.table(..., header = TRUE)`.

Yet, if you somehow cannot to do it, this solution may work for you:

```
set_first_row_name <- function(X) {
  X <- as.data.frame(X)
  # X should be a data frame
  names(X) <- X[1,]
  X[-1,]
}
for (the_one_table in list_all) {
  # list_all is your created name list of tables
  # Do set_first_row_name to each table and assign them back respectively
  assign(the_one_table, set_first_row_name(get(the_one_table)))
}
```

Comment: thanks, as I said there were lot of operations perform on original tables and many columns were deleted because of various reasons. So though header =True, it is immaterial. I don't want to list all tables in a list. I want to have them separately.

Comment: Then just `assign` in a `for` loop instead of `lapply` to meet your need of separating them.

Comment: @mr_swap I just revisited of my previous answers. Made some edits for you. I know it's been a long while but still you can see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
# put into a list and convert first row to header
list_all <- list(df1, df2, df3)

#convert first row to header
list_all <- lapply(
  list_all,
  function(df) {
    names(df) <- lapply(df[1, ], as.character)
    df <- df[-1,] 
    return(df)
  }
)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?